# How to check phonegap/cordova build errors

Tags: android, cordova

This may be a silly question but here it goes:

I'm developing my first app with phonegap, and currently targeting android only. But this is the second time I face this problems, in my project folder, through CLI I run `cordova build android`, the apks were not generated.

After a LONG time debugging, and undoing my recent changes. I finally tried to compile it in Eclipse, to check if it was an android compilation error, just to find out that I have copied some test images, and the names got `something copy (1).png`, and android don't allow that name...

So, How do I check, from command line, the logs/errors generated by phonegap/cordova buid?

Answer (score 8):

You can run the CLI in debug mode with the `-d` option.

```
cordova -d build android
```

This way you will get *a lot* more detailed report.

Comment: I just did it, and a lot of logs are printed indeed. But at the end "Platform "android" compiled successfully." was shown and no .apk generated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have this figured by now but just in case you, or anyone else still needs help, you may be encountering this issue because of your antivirus. I had a similar issue where when I tried to build my application. Though there were no errors being given, it was not building any APK's.

The fix for me in this situation was by temporarily disabling "Auto-Sandbox" in Comodo, (the antivirus I was using).

Hopefully this helps anyone having the same issue.